# Can you open a file in it's native program without having to be in the directory?

Tags: bash

I've tried using `explorer /c/x/y` and `start /c/x/y` to open file y (along path x) when I'm still in the root directory. The former just opens up another bash window and the latter sometimes opens the file, sometimes it opens another bash window. I know I can just use `cd /c/y` to get to the directory x is in and then open it with `explorer x` but I'd like to do it in one line of code if possible. Does anyone have any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try: `explorer c:\x\y`? It is a little unclear what you are asking for, why did you tag `git`?

Comment: Yes that doesn't work either. Unfortunately I can't think of another way to phrase it, beyond me hoping to open bash and go along a path and open a document in 1 line of code rather than 2 (by using ```cd /c/x``` to get to the directory y is in then ```explorer y```). Tagging git was a mistake on my part so I've removed that (thanks for pointing that out).

Comment: Let's assume that `y` is a text file, (i.e. `y.txt`), and  your example pathnames (`/c/x/`) are sub directories of the the root directory that you're currently in. You could run `Notepad c/x/y.txt`, i.e. tell the application _Notepad_ to open the file.

Comment: That's a useful suggestion, thank you. Do you know if there are similar commands for opening microsoft word documents (I use nano for Rmarkdown so that's fine)? I can't imagine there's a word one without downloading something like pandoc.